# I cant uninstall my mullvad VPN

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, uninstall, 64-bit, vpn

I tried sudo apt-get remove Mullvad-VPN  It showed me this command
Password for ubunt:
I tried severally to type in my system password and the passwords or words I typed after that dont show up. So I cant uninstall and I cant even use the app  after I tried to run an  update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the exact name of the package in the following way:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mullvad
ii  mullvad-vpn                   2020.6.0          amd64
```

then this is the right command line:

```
$ sudo apt purge mullvad-vpn
```

Comment: Thanks....it really worked......

Comment: Please help with the right commands again to try and install the latest version for ubuntu 64bit